# Firestore <Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type..>

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a list of `Objects` from a `collection` in `Firestore` like this:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore
        .getInstance()
        .collection("objects")
        .limit(10);

    query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshot,
            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        // Handle errors..

        ObjectList = snapshot.toObjects(ObjectModel.class);

        // Update UI..
    }
});
```

My object class:

```
public class ObjectModel {
    // Some other fields..
    private Double mPosition;

    public ObjectModel() { }

    public Double getPosition() { return mPosition; }

    public void setPosition(Double position) { mPosition = position; }
}
```

But then i get:

`Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double (found in field 'position')`

The `position` field is of a `Number` type, so, why am i getting a `String` instead?

**EDIT**

Document sample:

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document in the console that fails for this conversion?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added a screenshot, have a look please.

Comment: What if you change to primitive `double` instead of object `Double`?

Comment: @DougStevenson That didn't work. The field was actually created as `String` from a device, and then from another device, it got removed then re-created as a `Number`. So i changed my class to get a `String` and the error got reversed: `Failed to convert double to string`, then tried again to get a `Double` and it worked. Is that normal?

Comment: I've never heard of this sort of thing happening before.  Are you using the latest 15.0.0 SDK?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yep, i downgraded to 12.0.0 instead of updating to 15.0.0 =\ thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Doug Stevenson, the problem was that i accidentally downgraded to a lower version than the latest `15.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

In your class add:

```
//--PROPERTIES--
    @SerializedName("field1")
    @Expose
    private String field1;

    @SerializedName("field2")
    @Expose
    private String field2;


    //-----METHOD------
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fields1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fields2;
    }
```